# React Hooks - Updating string in real time

Tags: reactjs, string, react-hooks

I was told that to update a number in real time I should use something like this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

randomFunction = () => {
   setCount(count => count +1);
};
```

After I used this it worked as intended. I know for booleans is (current => !current). However, what is the equivalent for a string? I just can't find it.

Comment: There are many things you can do to a string. Your question needs more detail

Comment: `I know for booleans is (current => !current). However, what is the equivalent for a string?` Equivalent in what way? What modification do you want to do to the string?

Comment: I basically need to do this: setString("randomString"); However, unlike the eg I used originally with the numbers it does not update in real time. This is needed for a condition to be met

Comment: You keep mentioning "real time"; I don't know what you mean by that. The function version of set state is about calculating a new state from an old state, not about timing. So like, if you wanted to take the previous state and make it upper case, that would be `setString(prev => prev.toUpperCase())`. If it doesn't matter what the previous state is, it's find to do `setString("randomString")`

Comment: I am sorry, I am being unable to describe it properly. I have two if statements that check two things for test purposes. One if checks (if n = 1) and throws "works" in console. The other checks (if s="asd") and throws "works" in console aswell. Both are triggered by different buttons. However, only the if with the number works when I click the button. The if with the string requires to be clicked twice to work. I believe it is related to the way I update the state because if I do setCount(count+1) it also needs to be clicked twice to work in console.

Comment: Can you please add that code into your question. It sounds like a problem with stale closure variables, but i can't be sure without seeing it.

Comment: I was reviewing my code and noticed the difference. The "if" with the number check was also being run in console with an UseEffect that was far down below (i was testing many things and how do they work). The "if" with the string wasn't, and that was the reason I could see the changes in real time with the number but not the string. I am sorry I wasted your time

Answer (score -1):

I believe that just doing setting the desired constant to:

`useState("String in here")`

No where in any documentation have I seen that strings aren't allowed as useState payload, further I have personally used strings. I would always go check documentation to see what usage of things like useState is allowed as a rule of thumb.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In the end it was a non issue the way I updated it. I did it wrong in another part of the code so now it is fixed. Thanks anyway